# perl to strip span tags around words

Tags: perl, sed, replace

I'm trying to strip the span tags w/ a letter-spacing that starts with 0. or 1.

```
'<span style="letter-spacing:0.50 px">Boulevard,</span> '
to equal
'Boulevard, '
```

Thank you

Here's an example of a complete line.

```
<span style="letter-spacing:1.33 px">PRODUCTS</span> <span style="letter-spacing:1.37 px">MODEL</span> <span style="letter-spacing:0.77 px">HPI-27C</span> <span style="letter-spacing:1.39 px">MODDED)</span> ; <span style="letter-spacing:1.12 px">(HIGHWAY</span> <span style="letter-spacing:1.33 px">PRODUCTS</span> <span style="letter-spacing:1.37 px">MODEL</span>
```

Needs to end up like

PRODUCTS MODEL HPI-27C MODDED) ; (HIGHWAY PRODUCTS MODEL

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: Can you point me towards a tutorial so I can figure out how I can solve this problem.  Thanks

Comment: Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Sorry.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/HTML::Scrubber

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not exactly robust but does what you asked for given that 1 sample line you posted:

```
$ sed -E 's#<span[^>]+letter-spacing:[01][^>]+>(.*)</span>#\1#' file
'Boulevard, '
```

The above will work in any sed that supports `-E` for EREs, e.g. GNU sed and OSX sed.

Given your updated sample input/output, this will do what you want with GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='</span>' '{ORS=( sub(/<span[^>]+letter-spacing:[01][^>]+>/,"") ? "" : RT)}1' file
PRODUCTS MODEL HPI-27C MODDED) ; (HIGHWAY PRODUCTS MODEL
```

Comment: This helps, but when there are multiple instances per line I get this

"Total</span> TASK-HR</span> is the</span> tine</span> needed to do <span style="letter-spacing:1.02 px">all <span style="letter-spacing:0.32 px">services <span style="letter-spacing:0.54 px">(on-condition or"

Comment: All we have to go on is what you show us. You didn't show us an example with multiple instances on 1 line so YMMV with the answers you get. If the example in your question isn't truly representative of your real data then, obviously, edit your question so it is.

Comment: perfect.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using Perl and [`HTML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser) :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Parser ();
my $delete_tag = 0;

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
    api_version => 3,
    default_h => [sub { print shift }, 'text'],
    start_h => [\&start_handler, 'tagname,text,attr'],
    end_h => [\&end_handler, 'tagname,text'],    
);

my $str = do { local $/; <DATA> };
$p->parse($str) || die $!;
print "\n";

sub end_handler {
    my ( $tag, $text ) = @_;
    if ( $tag eq "span" ) {
        if ($delete_tag) {
            $delete_tag = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
    print $text;
}

sub start_handler {
    my ( $tag, $text, $attr ) = @_;
    if ( $tag eq "span" ) {
        if ($attr->{style} =~ /letter-spacing:[01]\./) {
            $delete_tag = 1;
            return;
        }
    }
    print $text;
}

__DATA__
<span style="letter-spacing:1.33 px">PRODUCTS</span> <span style="letter-spacing:1.37 px">MODEL</span> <span style="letter-spacing:0.77 px">HPI-27C</span> <span style="letter-spacing:1.39 px">MODDED)</span> ; <span style="letter-spacing:1.12 px">(HIGHWAY</span> <span style="letter-spacing:1.33 px">PRODUCTS</span> <span style="letter-spacing:1.37 px">MODEL</span>
```

**Output**:

```
PRODUCTS MODEL HPI-27C MODDED) ; (HIGHWAY PRODUCTS MODEL
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl oneliners:

1.) using the [Mojo::DOM58](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM58) module

```
perl -0777 -MMojo::DOM58 -E '$d=Mojo::DOM58->new(<>);$d->find("span")->grep(qr/letter-spacing:[01]/)->map(sub{$_->strip});print "$d"' <file.html
```

2.) Or if you have [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious) installed, you can use the [ojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo) module as:

```
perl -Mojo -E '$d=x(f("file.html")->slurp);$d->find("span")->grep(qr/letter-spacing:[01]/)->map(sub{$_->strip});print "$d"'
```

both examples prints:

```
PRODUCTS MODEL HPI-27C MODDED) ; (HIGHWAY PRODUCTS MODEL
```